# Can you start an ElasticJob at a specific step

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have an elastic job agent set up for an Azure SQL database.  The job has two steps (job.jobsteps) and has run correctly in the past.

If the job fails on the second step, I would like to restart it on the second step and not do the first step again.  Is there a way to accomplish this?  It doesn't look like there is.

An example (pseudo-code)

In this example - this is my Job X.  These are Job X's jobsteps (in real life they are T-SQL procedures)

step 1 - Create Tables

step 2 - Populate local Tables from extended tables

step 3 - do some data manipulation on the local tables and write them to new tables

1 - I create table A - it is empty

2 - I use my extended table B to populate table A

3 - I do some data manipulation and write my results to a new Table C

Now - let us say there is a problem with the data manipulation and the results in Table C are wrong or need some new logic added.

I change the logic in Step 3.  I don't need to recreate table A or repopulate it from B - I just want to to start Job X at step 3.

All job steps have a @retry_attempts set to 0 because I don't want them to try again if they fail.  If step 3 fails or gives me a questionable result - I will adjust the T-SQL procedure in step 3 and then want to start job X from Step 3.

Can that be done?

Please note - this is not actually what I am doing - just an illustrative example to explain the problem I am having.

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: When we exec `EXEC sp_add_jobstep` to add steps, we can set `@retry_attempts` properties, this is the number of retries when your step fails. [Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-add-jobstep-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples).

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I realise can do retry events but that isn't what I'm looking to do.  I have expanded my question to illustrate what I mean which is that I want to start the job from someplace other than the first jobstep.